# Coolest multi operation tricks to exploit 64bit registers ? (No SIMD/SSE/AVX)

Tags: optimization, assembly, bit-manipulation, sse

Im always eager to learn about the most extreme performance optimizations out there. Recently, ive been thinking alot about exploiting large registers. I feel guilty when ive got a one bit information sitting in a 64 bit register ... So i'd like to know tricks how I can do stuff like compare multiple 16 bits at once (e.g. Usefull when there is high probability none would match) or such. Ofc the most easiest example to check for whether atleast one element got a flag set is to xor a 0 register with those 64 bits and compare it for > 0. on the instruction level this ofc would exploit instr. Pipeline but anyways youre down to 2 instructions instead of 128 (each mov and cmp). Thats what I would call a whopping speedup!

Ofc Im aware that cache misses are what our cpus spend 95% of its time on, but lets assume the cache use would already be optimal.

Especially with trees, it would be usefull to compare multiple values without SIMD at once and get out a single childIndex to read next. In the end the instructions should be minimized and dont suffer too much from pipeline wait penaltys.

Other operations I could list up:

When put next to eachother with padding, e.g. 5x11 bits you do 5 additions, shifts, subtractions and bitwise operations in parallel. Or 7x 8bits. Ofc, one would need to store the data in that way and use the result efficiently to not pay a penalty on bitmask extraction/import.

Comment: A parallel way for multiple greater/lower thans would be to use a subtraction. The 'padding bits' on the right side then indicate wheter it is greater.. Those pad bits are on the other side of the add overflow padding bits. But ofc its an arithmetic operation not an bitwise operator so it needs to be used with care to actual runtime.

Comment: Why not use SIMD? it's designed for vectorization, unlike 64bit regs which would require you to manage the elements manually through bitmasks and would allow elements to overflow into one another

Comment: Sometimes its just not a problem to save the data in that packed format. And btw there is no overflow problem if you leave padding bit's in between the values.

Comment: It's too bad you exclude SSE. In Intel's manuals, the one instruction I find is the most obscenely powerful at the extremely specific single thing it does is the SSE4.1 instruction `MPSADBW`. Its pseudocode does 11 unsigned-byte absolute differences and 24 unsigned-byte additions. A toy benchmark I did a long time ago had MPSADBW outdo its pseudocode implemented in C by a factor of x20 or some ridiculous number like that. Allegedly `MPSADBW` can help you compute the sum of an 8x8 block of `uint8_t`'s in <7 cycles on average.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit subjective, but the coolest trick I know is called [bit slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_slicing). It belongs to the category of Distributed Arithmetics and especially useful when the length of each arithmetic operation is small and/or not some common size such as uint8_t.

Instead of packing 5 x 11 bits in a register, one associates a register for each bit in a vector.

```
  A[0] = 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 | 0 |
  A[1] = 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 | 0 |
  A[4] = 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1 |
                              R_0
```

Packing all the least significant bits to a single register R_0, or generally bit N to R_N, one can perform arithmetics for 64 vectors A[n] in parallel.

Most arithmetic operations would require k*11 instructions to complete, but some would have a better best / average case, such as A[] == B[], or A++, or even A < B starting from the MSB.

```
 // D = A == B
 for (i = 0, D=~0; D && i < 11; i++) D &= ~(A[i] ^ B[i]);
```

The caveat is that currently with the introduction of SIMD and openCL, the technique is most likely useful only for obfuscation. In the 90's the state of the art MD5 cracker utilized that; a [more recent version found from the net](http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2007/11/12/3) admits being 3x slower than a more conventional approach.

Comment: Hard to understand. It looks like it all depends on the bit-length of the operands. Have anybody tried yet to implement this with AVX and measure this against pure AVX for small numbers (e.g. 11 bits) ? Might be godlike.

Comment: Bit-slicing can definitely go a step further. If you want to see a cool way to transpose a bit matrix, check out:
http://mischasan.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/the-full-sse2-bit-matrix-transpose-routine/